# Simple ssh/telnet shell for debugging remote embedded device

Tags: shell, remote

I have an embedded device running some aarch64 Linux build, with busybox, but without sudo, nc, sshd, telnetd, /dev/tcp, /dev/udp, etc.

I would like to be able to remote in to run bash commands and see the output for debugging an application. The device allows me to upload extensions/applications (c++ code plus resource/library  files); is there any very simple code I can use to allow some form of shell access to this device?

I have tried opening bash with redirected stdin/stdout and communicating with is via UDP, but the stdout buffering makes it unusable, and I'm unable to turn it off.

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like you need to write a specialized shell

Comment: @user10489 how do you mean?

Comment: The standard shell expects to run on a pty or tty, possibly with a tcp connection.  So either you replace (ssh, telnet, tcp) with something that does udp, or you replace the shell itself with something that can accept commands from a different source and run commands without a pty.

Comment: I don't understand tty, except that it doesn't use a buffered pipe. I'm currently just calling system() to execute commands sent over UDP. Obvious issue is that a separate shell is used for each system() call, but it's workable.